# How to Decrease Height of Navigation bar in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have used MasterDetail page as main page of my app. Here TabbedPage is my detail page which contain various ContentPage as children of TabbedPage. I have set Details as Detail = NavigationPage(tabbedpage); it work great for IOS but in android it occupie more space in NavigationBar title and Tabbed Name, I cannot omit both, my question is how can i reduce the height of title bar of navigation page. 
Please check attached image for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set padding platform specific for example.

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FontAttributes" x:Key="fontAttributes">
        <OnPlatform.iOS>Bold</OnPlatform.iOS>
        <OnPlatform.Android>Italic</OnPlatform.Android>
</OnPlatform>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a CustomNavigationPage with a Custom renderer. Refer this - https://xamgirl.com/transparent-navigation-bar-in-xamarin-forms/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<NavigationPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="TransparentNavBarXForms.CustomNavigationPage"
    BarTextColor="White">
    <NavigationPage.BarBackgroundColor>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color">
            <On Platform="Android, iOS" Value="Transparent" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </NavigationPage.BarBackgroundColor>
</NavigationPage>

public partial class CustomNavigationPage : NavigationPage
{
    public CustomNavigationPage() : base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public CustomNavigationPage(Page root) : base(root)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public bool IgnoreLayoutChange { get; set; } = false;

    protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
    {
        if (!IgnoreLayoutChange)
            base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
    }
}

public class CustomNavigationPageRenderer : NavigationPageRenderer
{
    public CustomNavigationPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    IPageController PageController => Element as IPageController;
    CustomNavigationPage CustomNavigationPage => Element as CustomNavigationPage;

    protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        CustomNavigationPage.IgnoreLayoutChange = true;
        base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        CustomNavigationPage.IgnoreLayoutChange = false;

        int containerHeight = b - t;

        PageController.ContainerArea = new Rectangle(0, 0, Context.FromPixels(r - l), Context.FromPixels(containerHeight));

        for (var i = 0; i < ChildCount; i++)
        {
            AView child = GetChildAt(i);

            if (child is Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar)
            {
                continue;
            }

            child.Layout(0, 0, r, b);
        }
    }
}

public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new CustomNavigationPage(new MainPage());
    }
}
```